# Linguistic term for repeating a noun and replacing the first consonant with M

Tags: terminology

Usually the speaker intends something like "and similar"

I have seen this usage in several languages, e.g. Turkish, Slovakian, Russian, Polish. But i have not heard it in English, German or French

Examples can be found e.g. in Restaurant names like:
Pizza Mizza.
pasta masta.
Sushi Mushi
Kebap Mebap (or Döner Möner)

What is this concept called, and where does it originate?

Comment: In Hindi it is 'va'...Pasta vasta. Hey wait there are attested usages of 'sh' also...but never both with the same word...do you have examples of this in Sanskrit?

Answer (score 8):

I think it's a type of reduplication. As noted above, English has a similar process, replacing the first onset with *schm-*. A language that has this in spades is Thai, with several types of reduplication with internal changes (usually to the vowel).

Answer (score 7):

In English, we use "shm-".  See [The phonology of shm-reduplication](http://www.academia.edu/209796/Metalinguistic_shmetalinguistic_The_phonology_of_shm-reduplication)

Comment: English shminglish!  That reduplication type came out of Yiddish.

Comment: @dwoz. Indeed. And it is really only common in East-Coast US English.

Comment: Paper title in the link: "*Metalinguistic shmetalinguistic: The phonology of shm-reduplication*." Linguistics papers have the *goofiest* titles.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can be rephrased so that it more clearly answers the question: "What is this concept called, and where does it originate?"